# Check elements from array are not visible

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, page-object-gem, rspec-expectations

I have an array with elements' names:

```
names=['tdColumn1','tdColumn2','tdColumn3']
```

And I wan't to check that they are not visible:

```
expect(actual).to all(not_be_visible)
```

But `be_not_visible`, `not_visible`, `not_be_visible`, `.not_to all(be_visible)` are not correct methods.
What method is correct?

Comment: are these html elements?

Comment: Yes, they are. Described via Page-Object

Comment: can you share the part of html code you want to work on?

Comment: It is just a simple TD which becomes visible/invisible when I check/uncheck checkbox. When I check visibility `expect(actual).to all(be_visible)` it works. But I need a method for check invisible.

Comment: `expect(actual).to none(be_visible)`

Comment: Types `undefined method 'none' for`

Comment: Oh, indeed. Strange. Anyway: `expect(actual.map(&:visible?)).to all(be_falsey)`

Comment: Thank you. It is closer for idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the array without iterating through it yourself but using the include & all matchers/modifiers. The best ones for this case would be .not_to + include.

```
expect(names).not_to include(be_visible)
```

A less sexy solution would be to match !(false) which = true.

```
expect(names).to all(!(be_visible))
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each name and ensure the page does not have that text:

```
names=['tdColumn1','tdColumn2','tdColumn3']

names.each do |name|
  expect(page).not_to have_text name
end
```